# Make Tomcat use X-Real-IP

Tags: nginx, tomcat

I'm configuring nginx as a reverse proxy in front of Tomcat 7. I added the following lines to nginx configuration:

```
set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
...
location / {
    proxy_pass http://tomcat;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

But still, I see in Tomcat logs the following picture:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2013:11:25:48 +0600] "GET /app/welcome;jsessionid=6C1B02376C5F748C509B28FC7CE416C9 HTTP/1.0" 200 10571
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2013:11:25:48 +0600] "GET /app/welcome;jsessionid=0BBE0174C1F0E94FDF49610144E809D3 HTTP/1.0" 200 10571
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Jun/2013:11:25:48 +0600] "GET /app/welcome;jsessionid=AD48005AD453F3A0BE46F1AC978F145D HTTP/1.0" 200 10571
```

Is there any way to force Tomcat to use X-Real-IP header (and write it to log files) **without modifying** web app?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's required to add Valve in Tomcat configuration:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
               remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For"
               requestAttributesEnabled="true"
               internalProxies="127\.0\.0\.1"  />
```

After that Tomcat starts to dispatch headers passed from nginx:

```
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

Comment: As per the [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html), `internalProxies` is expecting a regular expression, not a string literal.  As such, `127.0.0.1` should please be `127\.0\.0\.1`.

Comment: requestAttributesEnabled goes in the AccessLogValve, not the RemoteIpValve, in Tomcat 7/8. Also, remoteIpHeader="X-Forwarded-For" is not required as that is the default value.

Comment: requestAttributesEnabled=true is the default in Tomcat 9.

Answer (score 5):

Found this question via google, and want to add comment to the approved answer:

According to [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Remote_IP_Valve/Introduction), by default this valve (RemoteIpValve) has no effect on the values that are written into access log. In order to get real IPs in log, you should add

```
requestAttributesEnabled="true"
```

to AccessLogValve also.

Answer (score 2):

Another useful example of Tomcat config: 
**internalProxies** can be separated with pipeline (|) since accepts regular expression.

```
<Valve
   className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve"
   internalProxies="192\.168\.10\.110|127\.0\.0\.1"
   remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for"
   proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by"
   protocolHeader="x-forwarded-proto"
   />
```

For more examples refer to [tomcat document](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/valves/RemoteIpValve.html)

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same thing and found information leading me to the following solution from researching around the net.

In your tomcat **server.xml** you need to edit the logging valve pattern to get the values from the incoming header.

In your

and change the pattern to:

```
pattern="Remote User[ %{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t ] Request[ &quot;%r&quot; ] Status Code[ %s ] Bytes[ %b ] Referer[ &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; ] Agent[ &quot;%{User-agent}i&quot; ] "
```

My full access log value looks like the following:

```
      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
               prefix="access_log." suffix=".txt"
               pattern="Remote User[ %{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t ] Request[ &quot;%r&quot; ] 
               Status Code[ %s ] Bytes[ %b ] Referer[ &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; ] 
               Agent[ &quot;%{User-agent}i&quot; ] " />
```

This is accompanied by the Nginx config of:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
}
```

Additional information of log valve patterns in Tomcat can be found at: [Apache 7: The Valve Component](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Access_Log_Valve)

Comment: The `%{X-Forwarded-For}i` was key for me, thanks.  Unfortunately, the newer answer at https://serverfault.com/a/746395/165500 did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to install mod_realip http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_remoteip.html  (http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Remote_IP_Filter)  or mod_rpaf at the apache server.